# How do we create an IObservableList<T> from an IObservable<IList<T>>?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive, reactiveui

#### Question

How do we go from an `IObservable<IReadOnlyList<T>>` to an `IObservableList<T>` (from [DynamicData](https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData#dynamic-data))?

#### Context

I'm using both [Reactive extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive#reactive-extensions) and [DynamicData](https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData#dynamic-data) in my project.

I currently have a list of strings that changes over time. I have at as an `IObservable<IReadOnlyList<string>>`. It yields updates like the following:

1. `["A", "C", "F"]`
2. `["A", "B", "C", "F"]`
3. `["A", "B", "C"]`

I want to convert this into an `IObservableList<string>` that would yield updates like the following:

1. Add "A","C","F" at index 0
2. Add "B" at index 1
3. Remove "F" from index 3

#### What I've tried

I've tried using the `ToObservableChangeSet` extension, but it doesn't have the correct behavior for my case.

Code

```cs
Subject<IReadOnlyList<string>> source = new Subject<IReadOnlyList<string>>();
IObservable<IEnumerable<string>> observableOfList = source;
IObservable<IChangeSet<string>> observableOfChangeSet = source.ToObservableChangeSet<string>();

observableOfChangeSet
    .Bind(out ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> boundCollection)
    .Subscribe();

((INotifyCollectionChanged)boundCollection).CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;

source.OnNext(new[] { "A", "C", "F" });
source.OnNext(new[] { "A", "B", "C" });

void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(", ", (IEnumerable<string>)sender)}] (operation: {e.Action} at index {e.NewStartingIndex})");
}
```

Output

```
[A, C, F] (operation: Reset at index -1)
[A, C, F, A] (operation: Add at index 3)
[A, C, F, A, B] (operation: Add at index 4)
[A, C, F, A, B, C] (operation: Add at index 5)
```

As we can see `[A, C, F, A, B, C]` is not the same as `[A, B, C]`.

---

I've also tried using `EditDiff`, but that doesn't preserve the order of the list.

Code

```cs
Subject<IReadOnlyList<string>> source = new Subject<IReadOnlyList<string>>();
IObservable<IEnumerable<string>> observableOfList = source;
IObservable<IChangeSet<string>> observableOfChangeSet = ObservableChangeSet.Create<string>(list =>
{
    return observableOfList
        .Subscribe(items => list.EditDiff(items, EqualityComparer<string>.Default));
});

observableOfChangeSet
    .Bind(out ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> boundCollection)
    .Subscribe();

((INotifyCollectionChanged)boundCollection).CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;

source.OnNext(new[] { "A", "C", "F" });
source.OnNext(new[] { "A", "B", "C" });

void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(", ", (IEnumerable<string>)sender)}] (operation: {e.Action} at index {e.NewStartingIndex})");
}
```

Output

```
[A, C, F] (operation: Reset at index -1)
[A, C] (operation: Remove at index -1)
[A, C, B] (operation: Add at index 2)
```

As we can see `[A, C, B]` is not the same as `[A, B, C]`.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using the EditDiff instead. Something like https://github.com/RolandPheasant/DynamicData.Snippets/blob/bdb614dd58f112df47694617b46928f98c0c437a/DynamicData.Snippets/Creation/ChangeSetCreation.cs#L36

Comment: @GlennWatson That almost worked! However, the order of the list is not preserved using `EditDiff`. I've edited the question to add that sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom solution.

It's open source and nuget packages are also available.

- Code: https://github.com/jeanplevesque/CollectionTracking#collectiontracking
- Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CollectionTracking.DynamicData

To solve the original issue, install the following packages.

- `CollectionTracking.DynamicData`
- `System.Reactive`

Then you can use a method like the following.

```cs
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using CollectionTracking;
// ...
public static class DynamicDataExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts <see cref="IObservable{IEnumerable}"/> to <see cref="IObservableList{T}"/>.
    /// Keeps the same ordering, which is why we use .GetOperations and not .EditDiff.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of items in list.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="observableOfList"><see cref="IObservable{IEnumerable}"/> to convert.</param>
    /// <returns>Converted <see cref="IObservableList{T}"/>.</returns>
    public static IObservableList<T> ToObservableList<T>(this IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> observableOfList)
    {
        return observableOfList
            .StartWith(Enumerable.Empty<T>())
            .Buffer(2, 1)
            .Select(lists => lists[0].GetOperations(lists[1]).ToChangeSet())
            .AsObservableList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with DynamicData, but I believe that this gives something close to the desired outcome:

```cs
using DynamicData;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Subject<IReadOnlyList<string>> source = new Subject<IReadOnlyList<string>>();

            var list = ObservableChangeSet.Create<string>(sourceList =>
            {
                return source
                    .Subscribe(newItems =>
                    {
                        sourceList.Edit(items =>
                        {
                            for (var i = 0; i < newItems.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (items.Count <= i) items.Add(newItems[i]);
                                else
                                {
                                    if (items[i] != newItems[i])
                                    {
                                        items[i] = newItems[i];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            while (items.Count > items.Count) items.RemoveAt(items.Count - 1);
                        });
                    });
            }).AsObservableList();

            source.OnNext(new[] { "A", "C", "F" });
            source.OnNext(new[] { "A", "B", "C", "F" });
            source.OnNext(new[] { "A", "B", "C" });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I didn't figure out how to get `Add "B" at index 1`, but the current output is as follows:

1. `AddRange. 3 changes`
2. `3 Changes`

   - `Replace. Current: B, Previous: C`
   - `Replace. Current: C, Previous: F`
   - `Add. Current: F, Previous: <None>`
3. `Remove. Current: C, Previous: <None>`

**Edit:** The following gives the exact output you want, but I have not tested the performance of each (Insert will likely get expensive for larger lists):

```cs
using DynamicData;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Subject<IReadOnlyList<string>> source = new Subject<IReadOnlyList<string>>();

            var list = ObservableChangeSet.Create<string>(sourceList =>
            {
                return source
                    .Subscribe(newItems =>
                    {
                        sourceList.Edit(items =>
                        {
                            for (var i = 0; i < newItems.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (items.Count <= i) items.Add(newItems[i]);
                                else
                                {
                                    if (items[i] != newItems[i])
                                    {
                                        items.Insert(i, newItems[i]);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            while (items.Count > newItems.Count) items.RemoveAt(items.Count - 1);
                        });
                    });
            }).AsObservableList();

            source.OnNext(new[] { "A", "C", "F" });
            source.OnNext(new[] { "A", "B", "C", "F" });
            source.OnNext(new[] { "A", "B", "C" });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

1. `AddRange. 3 changes`
2. `Add. Current: B, Previous: <None> Index 1`
3. `Remove. Current: C, Previous: <None> Index 2`

Comment: @Batesias I am not sure if there is a notification for this answer as I deleted the original after realizing that I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

If strings are unique, why don't you use the overload of `ToObservableChangeSet` where you set the string as the key.  That way, if your new list doesn't contain "F", it knows that your existing "F" should be removed.

Maybe there's an easier way but you might have to insert your own index temporarily.  If you don't need to track the changes via the bound collection, you can do it from the changeset like this:

```
Subject<IReadOnlyList<string>> source = new Subject<IReadOnlyList<string>>();
IObservable<IEnumerable<string>> observableOfList = source;
IObservable<IChangeSet<(string,int),string>> observableOfChangeSet = source.Select(x => 
            {
                return x.Select((item, index) => (item, index));
            }).ToObservableChangeSet<(string,int),string>(x=>x.Item1);

observableOfChangeSet
    .Sort(SortExpressionComparer<(string, int)>.Ascending(x => x.Item2))
    .OnItemAdded(x=> Debug.WriteLine($"Item {x.Item1} was added to index {x.Item2}"))
    .OnItemRemoved(x => Debug.WriteLine($"Item {x.Item1} was removed from index {x.Item2}"))
    .OnItemUpdated((x,prev) => Debug.WriteLine($"Item {prev.Item1} at index {prev.Item2} was updated to Item {x.Item1} at index {x.Item2}"))
    .Transform(x=>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Item: {x.Item1} at index: {x.Item2}");
           return x.Item1;
        })
    .Bind(out ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> boundCollection)
    .Subscribe();

source.OnNext(new[] { "A", "C", "F" });
source.OnNext(new[] { "A", "B", "C" });
```

My debug output for this code:

```
Item A was added to index 0
Item C was added to index 1
Item F was added to index 2
Item: A at index: 0
Item: C at index: 1
Item: F at index: 2
Item B was added to index 1
Item F was removed from index 2
Item A at index 0 was updated to Item A at index 0
Item C at index 1 was updated to Item C at index 2
Item: A at index: 0
Item: B at index: 1
Item: C at index: 2
```

Comment: Clever! I'm not sure I understand this line though:
`Item A at index 0 was updated to Item A at index 0`?

Comment: I believe that since the new list (A,B,C) contains something that already exists in the cache (the item with key "A"), it assumes I am trying to update it even though the contents are the same.  That must be a limitation of using ToObservableChangeSet to convert observables of lists.